# sfdx sobject refresh

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm getting the below error.  I have my dev hub set as default and authorized.  How to fix?

> Starting SFDX: Refresh SObject Definitions
>
> 20:37:49.980 sfdx sobject definitions refresh
>   Failure performing sObject describe Must pass a username and/or OAuth options when creating an AuthInfo instance.
>
> 20:37:53.892 sfdx sobject definitions refresh ended with error Failure performing sObject describe Must pass a username and/or OAuth options when creating an AuthInfo instance.
>
> 20:37:53.892 sfdx sobject definitions refresh ended with exit code 1

Comment: please authorize your org with sfdx and try again.

Comment: Go to your personal setting and then to Authentication Settings for External Systems  then clear the VS code authentication and reconnect

Comment: @AvijitChakraborty - can you please clarify where I can find the Authentication Settings for external systems? I'm new to SFDX and not sure which settings you meant here. I tried to authorize my org, but still facing the same error OP mentioned here